# Write Array of strings to file

Tags: c

Can someone please tell me how to use write() to write an array of strings to a file? PLEASE

```
char *arr[1000];
for (int i =0; i < strlen(arr)-1; i++){
    printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
}
```

This prints all the strings just fine to stdout as expected.

```
This is very good
text that has been
put into a file for
the purposes of
being an example.
```

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(arr)-1; i++) {
    write(fd_write, arr[i], 100); 
}
```

This prints over and over strings plus questions marks into the file

```
This is a very goodtext that has beenput into a file forthe purposes ofbeing an example.text that has beenput into a file forthe purposes ofbeing an example.�%�put into a file forthe purposes ofbeing an example.�%�:s*�the purposes ofbeing an example.�%�:s*������Kbeing an example.�%�:s*������K�pc^���
```

I just want to know how to do this the right way Please. To write an array of strings to a file

Okay i did what someone told me and now The string is looking better so for adding \n i did this

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(arr)-1; i++) {
   write(fd_write, arr[i],  strlen(arr[i]));
   write(fd_write, "\n", 1);
}
```

Okay this worked perfectly. Thank you guys

Comment: Are all your strings 100 chars long?

Comment: [fopen](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) and [fprintf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fprintf) will be your friends

Comment: i have to use open() read() and write(). I wish i can use fopen and fprintf

Comment: The `printf` format `%s` *stops* at the null-terminator in the string. Perhaps you should do as well? Also remember that the `printf` call ends with a newline, something which you do not write.

Comment: `write(fd_write, arr[i], strlen(arr[i])); ` then `write(fd_write, "\n", 1)`

Comment: You can't use `strlen` on `arr`. `strlen` is only used on a single string to get its length, not on a general array.

Comment: Thank you soo mach guys I really appreciate your time. It is working as expected.

Comment: `for (int i =0; i < 1000; i++){`

Comment: BTW - Someone does have a name

Comment: Ed Heal my friend you deserve a tap on the back. Thank you